# GraphQL on azure server

Tags: node.js, azure, reactjs, graphql

I'm trying ti deploy a NodeJS App to Azure. Everything works fine including react. but when I'm trying to hit the GraphQL server I'm getting a 404 Error

*The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.*

Any Ideas?

Here is my index.js

```
'use strict'
require('babel-core/register')
import schema from './data/schema'
import GraphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql'
import express from 'express'
const multer = require('multer')
const insert = require('./business/insert')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json()) // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // support encoded bodies
app.use('/graphql', GraphQLHTTP({
  schema,
  graphiql: true
}))

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('view engine', 'html')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/upload/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '.xlsx')
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening http://localhost:8080')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this document https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/ it appears that tooling for ES6 only happens via the next *requires*

> All subsequent files required by node with the extensions .es6, .es, .jsx and .js will be transformed by Babel.

So you'll need something like this instead:

```
// app.js
'use strict'
require('babel-core/register')
require('./index')

// index.js
import schema from './data/schema'
import GraphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql'
import express from 'express'
const multer = require('multer')
const insert = require('./business/insert')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json()) // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // support encoded bodies
app.use('/graphql', GraphQLHTTP({
  schema,
  graphiql: true
}))

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('view engine', 'html')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/upload/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '.xlsx')
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening http://localhost:8080')
})
```